# What is the Halacha regarding Tachanun and Brit in the same shul?

Tags: halacha, tzibur-community, brit-milah, tachanun

I don't have the ArtScroll weekday Siddur in front of me, now, but essentially, it said that one does not say Tachanun in a shul where a Brit will occur during that day.

If a Brit occurs anywhere in the shul building at any time during that day, and if the Brit is performed by anyone whatsoever, even an outsider who is renting a room for the Brit later in the day, does no one in the morning minyan say Tachanun? Is this how the halacha works, or is Tachanun omitted only if one of the people involved in the Brit (father, mohel, Sandak, etc.) is actually davening with the minyan?

Comment: If you are asking about a detail in a specific line in that book it would really improve your question to quote it precisely.

Answer (score 3):

*Mishna B'rura* (131:24, *Shaar Hatziyun* :21) says those who pray in the synagogue's lobby without an *aron* (cabinet for the Torah scrolls) and *teva* (lectern) are thereby "drawn after" the synagogue and so skip *tachanun* if the *b'ris* will be in the main synagogue (and even if the participants in the *b'ris* are absent for the service). It seems from his wording that if there's a separate room **with** an *aron*, the people praying there would **not** skip *tachanun*, and that, conversely, those praying at a separate *minyan* in the same room as the *b'ris* (before the *b'ris*'s *minyan*) **would** skip *tachanun* (as they'd a fortiori be considered part of the synagogue), but those are merely my own inferences and you should consult your own rabbi for a ruling. Likewise, it seems (even less certainly) from his wording that if the *b'ris* will be in an event hall in the synagogue's basement, people in the synagogue would **not** skip *tachanun*, as I doubt they're not "drawn after" the event hall; again, consult your rabbi.

In any event, if the *sandek*, *mohel*, or father is praying with a *minyan*, it skips *tachanun*.